# What side effects occur when reusing generator names?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, uniqueidentifier

I'm working in a code base of a couple dozen tables. I went to add a new class and, naturally, I'm going to look at what has been written before I got on the project to see how it's done over there. Something about wheel engineering?

Anyway, here's what I find

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "identifier", sequenceName = "LIMIT_REASON_COLL_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "identifier")
@Column(name = "ID")
```

Of note is the `name = "identifier"` and `generator = "identifier`. I didn't replace anything, that's actually what it says. And it's called `"identifier"` in every class managed by Hibernate.

Now, the system has been stable for years, so clearly it doesn't appear to impact whatever we're doing (that we can observe). But are there any side effects to reusing the generator name in this way? Is it advised, and if it isn't why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SequenceGenerator's **name** and the GeneratedValue's **generator** can be whatever you choose to name them.

It's the GeneratedValue's **strategy** that references one of the Hibernate identifier generators:

- increment
- identity
- sequence
- hilo
- seqhilo
- uuid
- uuid2
- guid
- assigned
- select
- foreign

There is no association between the generator's name and the strategy. So you can call your sequence generator by the "identity" name.

Comment: If there's no connection, why do we name them in the first place?

Comment: Good question. Because you can define the generators at class or package level in order to reuse them across your domain level.

Comment: So if I don't use a unique name, it might increment for any one of them? Why haven't I observed that behavior in my application?

Comment: You can have the same generator name in all your classes, there no clashing. The name is more useful when declaring one common generator at package level that you want to reuse, but each entity has it's own generator instance anyway. It's the configuration that gets shared in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks, that's the exact information I'm looking for. So the answer is "no side effects" if I stick to the paradigm currently used, i.e. defining a generator on every getId() method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will face problem related to `duplicate key violation..` or somthing like this. Someday before i searched for the same and I got this post : [JPA 2 @SequenceGenerator @GeneratedValue producing unique constraint violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993889/jpa-2-sequencegenerator-generatedvalue-producing-unique-constraint-violation) . Please go though Question and answer.

Comment: Interesting - except that's never happened. It's been in production like this for years. I checked the sequences and they are all being updated independently like they're supposed to.

Comment: Even i also surprised. One of my friend shared this link with me.After this I cross checked my error log and warn log file and DB/squ also looks good, But don't know I found similar so ishared to you..